# SpringBoot How to know which @Value are using default value?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have lots of `@Value("${aaa.bbb:default}` in the source code.

But some properties are missing in *.properties files thus default values are used.

How can I get a list of all the fields whose property is missing and @Value is using default value instead of value in properties file?

I want to know where did spring do the loading of @Value so I can set a breakpoint there.

Or are there any logs warning about this?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can set breakpoint on this line [PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java#L161](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/1469bdbc70ac78b0c13b7bbaeb54a91dce6e8493/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/util/PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java#L161)
2. Get list of all the properties which are injected using `@Value` by using Intellij search across project feature
   and then with the help of `spring-boot-actuator` get list of properties present in Spring's `ConfigurableEnvironment` using `/env` endpoint, any property which is used in `@Value` but it is not there in `actuator` response for that property default value will be used.